# C# sorting file by distance between elements

Tags: c#, arrays, file, sorting, distance

I have text file that looks something like this

```
LINE 325,474 195,251 589,821 375,711 Nan Nan Nan
LINE 617,303 578,402 771,724 392,711 Nan Nan Nan
LINE 424,931 472,48 481,203 617,633 Nan Nan Nan
```

Where first column is basically name of element, second is starting X coordinate, third is starting Y coordinate, fourth and fifth are ending X and Y coordinates, others are not important.
I need to sort them by distance between each line. My code looks something like this:

```
        string[] Text = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFile.Filename);
        string[,] Word = new string[Text.Length, 8];
        double CurXpos = 0; // for smallest distance set new points (starting from 0,0)
        double CurYpos = 0;
        string[] word = new string[8];
        for (long i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++) // read text 
        {                
            string line = Text[i];               

                for (byte j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    word = line.Split(' ');
                    Word[i, j] = word[j]; //store text to 2D array
                }
        }
        StreamWriter FileSorted = new StreamWriter(desired destination);
        for (long i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++) // search for minimal distance
        {
            double X1 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3); // X start possition to double
            double Y1 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 2], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3); //Y , etc.
            double X2 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 3], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3);
            double Y2 = Math.Round(double.Parse(Word[i, 4], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 3);
            double[] XPos = new double[Text.Length]; // array of smallest distances for each line
            double[] YPos = new double[Text.Length];
            double MinDis1 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X1 - CurXpos, 2) + Math.Pow(Y1 - CurXpos, 2)); //calculation of the smallest distances
            double MinDis2 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X2 - CurXpos, 2) + Math.Pow(Y2 - CurYpos, 2)); //calculate if end points are closer                
            long PosMin = 0; //position of line with minimum
            double[] AbsMinDis = new double[Text.Length]; // line containing distance data of each line
            if (MinDis1 < MinDis2) // if distance of starting coordinate is smaller than ending, save 
            {
                AbsMinDis[i] = MinDis1;
                XPos[i] = X1;
                YPos[i] = Y1;

            }
            else if (MinDis2 < MinDis1) // if distance of ending points is smaller, swap starting end endinng points and save line possition
            {
                AbsMinDis[i] = MinDis2;
                XPos[i] = X2;
                YPos[i] = Y2;
                Word[i, 1] = X2.ToString();
                Word[i, 2] = Y2.ToString();
                Word[i, 3] = X1.ToString();
                Word[i, 4] = Y1.ToString();                    
            }
            for (long j = 0; j < Text.Length; j++) //sorting file 
            {
                if (AbsMinDis[i] < AbsMinDis[PosMin])
                {                       
                    CurXpos = XPos[i];
                    CurYpos = YPos[i];
                    string swap = Word[PosMin, j];
                    Word[PosMin, j] = Word[i, j];
                    Word[i, j] = swap;
                    PosMin = i;
                }
```

Now I don't know if I have there any error, or if I don't know how to write it, because it looks like, it does nothing with file
Writing looks like this:

```
            FileSorted.Write(Word[i, 0]);
            for (byte k = 1; k < 8; k++)
            {
                FileSorted.Write(" {0}", Word[i, k]);
            }
            FileSorted.WriteLine();
        }
        FileSorted.Close();
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: It would be easier to read, if you write your variable names with a small letter at the beginning.

Comment: How do you mean that? Sorry, I am new to C#

Comment: So what is the result of the code execution? any error? empty file? no file at all?

Comment: @DanielFrühauf - all a matter of personal preference & background. Doesn't help the OP in the slightest with his problem.

Comment: Rewriting of file, or bad sort @KernelMode

Comment: StackOverflow formats the code on how it's written. When you write "Word" for your 2-D array, it's colored and you would think, it's a class, because of the color.

Comment: And yes, does it throw an error earlier? Becaues the file export should work as I see it.

Comment: Rewriting of file is not a bad result if you use the same name of file (it is the expected result). So your problem is bad sorting. right?

Comment: @Daniel Frühauf sorry, next time, I will use different name. And I don't know, if sort is bad, or I should save it to different array. Code doesn't throw any error, but export is bad

Comment: @KernelMode I think so, but not sure, if it is export or sort

Answer (score 0):

There is a failure writing to `SortedFile` in other iterations of `i` (except the first) because you close the file at the end of iteration:

```
FileSorted.Close();
```

if you move `FileSorted.Close()` after you have done with all the iterations of `i`, then you will see all lines in the `SortedFile`.

The line duplication is because when writing to the file where you comment "//sorting file", you are writing the line `i` times instead of once.

And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) you can see the capitalization conventions.